# Discord.jsでbotを作成していてコマンドが実行されるとエラーが出る

Tags: javascript, discord

Discordの音楽再生コマンドを見様見真似で作っていたのですが、
**DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message**
というエラーが出てコマンドが実行できません。

コマンド↓

```
if(command === "test" || command === "ts"){
        try{
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
         connection.play(ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6qBZPt3lck", {
          filter: 'audioonly'
}))
        }catch(error){
          message.channel.send(error) 
          return;
        }
      }
```

**エラー全文**

```
RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\i3 550\desktop\Soft\akikaki\agile-island-80543\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\i3 550\desktop\Soft\akikaki\agile-island-80543\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/863359143267139594/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.channel.send(error.message)`
に変更してみてください。
エラーメッセージの送信部分で詰まっているんだと思います。

Comment: ytdl is not definedと出ました。これはytdlが定義されていないってことですかね？

Comment: const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')とやったら解決しました。つぶあん派さん、ありがとうございました！